# Changing file EOL with vscode extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, eol

Can I silently change end of line sequence in VSCode?
Something like this:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.editor.changeEOL", "LF");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to call `edit` method of active `TextEditor`. For example:

```js
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(builder => { 
    builder.setEndOfLine(vscode.EndOfLine.LF);
})
```

**UPD**
Or if you want `TexEdit` result you can use this one:

```js
vscode.TextEdit.setEndOfLine(vscode.EndOfLine.LF)
```

"vscode" here is vscode module: `require('vscode')`

Comment: Is this a script snippet ? How to execute it ?

Comment: @Alan, you need to call `edit` method of `TextEditor` object. For example:
`require('vscode').window.activeTextEditor.edit(builder => { builder.setEndOfLine(vscode.EndOfLine.LF); })`

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, it would be improved with simpler instructions within the body and not a comment. Specifically how would one "call the edit method" for example.

Comment: It might be the solution but it should contain the instructions as to where and how a person should execute the code. Poorly answered.

Comment: This question is about VSCode extension development. I produced a code, that solves the problem. Where and how execute the code (of extension you're working at) is not the instruction for this question i hope)

Answer (score 13):

You can add this line to your user preferences settings (`CTRL + ,`):

```
"files.eol": "\n"
```

Answer (score 5):

On the bottom right of vs code it will say lf or crlf. Click there and it will give an option to change.

[image: pic of vs code]

Comment: That only applies it to the current file. Is there a way to change it for every file in the project? Just changing it in the Settings does not do this unfortunately.