# Changing EOL to "LF" using Extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a simple extension for changing EOL type of the opened document.
But the `executeCommand()` wasn't working.
It's just showing a popup command to choose "LF" or "CRLF" option.

`const vscode = require('vscode')`
`vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.editor.changeEOL', 'LF')`

How to directly executes command to change EOL to "LF" without select popup option?

VS Code v1.44.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing file EOL in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404044/changing-file-eol-in-vscode)

Comment: @Gama11 `builder.setEndOfLine(vscode.EndOfLine.LF)` was working fine after using `setTimeout()` method for delay call. Thanks.